# Parameter support in rosserial?

Tags: ros, rosserial, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a rosserial node for reading some sensor values, and I was hoping to pull in a few parameters. There seems to be support in the code, and there's an [old documentation page here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Parameters) (which isn't actually linked-to from the main documentation). This is my code:

```
void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub);

  while(!nh.connected()) {
    nh.spinOnce();
  }

  nh.getParam("devices", device_counts, 3);
  nh.getParam("rate", &rate);
}
```

I consistently get `Tried to publish before configured, topic id 6`, which is the parameter-fetch magic topic. I'm using Electric on an Oneiric system, with the rosserial debs. (I'm aware that I haven't got default values in here; I've removed those blocks, for simplicity of presentation.)

Is parameter server support incomplete in rosserial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27596/parameter-support-in-rosserial?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tested out using the parameter server through rosserial_arduino, and it seems to work fine. There were a couple of bugs (see [ticket](https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/ticket/58)), but only if the parameter request failed.

I suspect that this error may have gotten resolved sometime over the past couple of months. I did use the rosserial source (for the Arduino 1.0 support) and ROS Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2